Convert SharePoint On-Premise Publishing Pages to Modern Page - 'Connect-PnPOnline' not working
I am trying to convert On-Premise (SharePoint 2013) Classic Publishing pages to SharePoint online (Modern) pages. I am trying to follow the example given in below article:
https://pnp.github.io/script-samples/modernize-classic-pages-from-publishing-sites/README.html?tabs=pnppsv2
I am getting stuck at the very first step itself when I am trying to get a connection object from SharePoint 2013 on-prem environment:
$sp13Conn = Connect-PnPOnline "" -Credentials OnPrem -ReturnConnection -TransformationOnPrem

I also registered an Entra ID App in Azure to use with PnP by following below articles:
https://pnp.github.io/powershell/articles/registerapplication.html
Still, I am unable to connect to SharePoint 2013 On-Prem environmet using 'Connect-PnPOnline'.
Environment Details:

I am using latest PnP.PowerShell to execute PowerShell script.
PowerShell version 7.2 (Visual Studio Code)

Any help will be appreciated.

SharePoint 2013 doesn’t support modern pages.

@Greg W, that's the purpose of the script to convert classic 2013 pages to modern pages.

@Gopal Tiwari, did you check my answer?

SharePoint 2013 is also EoL.

The change introduces in September 2024 is only for SharePoint Online in Microsoft 365.
If you want to connect to SharePoint Server 2013, you have to use the old PowerShell module: SharePointPnPPowerShell2013
Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShell2013

You can force the version for 2013 before the fist line of you script:
Import-Module SharePointPnPPowerShell2013

Unfortunately, the provided code can not work anymore. Author also mentions that This script uses the older SharePoint PnP PowerShell Online module and THESE SAMPLES ARE PROVIDED AS IS WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND. You have to split the process in two:

connect to SharePoint 2013 to export classic pages
connect to SharePoint Online to import and convert the classic pages to modern pages

References:

How to change versions of PnP PowerShell
How to Install Sharepoint 2013 Powershell Module on Windows 10 Powershell


@ jleture, There is some confusion which PowerShell Module to use:
I had asked this question to PnP Community as well and there I was advised to use PnP.PowerShell v. 1.12.
You have advised me to use SharePointPnPPowerShell2013
I will try both advises one by one and let you know if any of the suggestions worked or not.
